# Why do I receive an "Expected expression" error at every "else"?

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors

This algorithm must print four numbers in crescent order. When I start it, I receive an error: "Expected expression". Why does this happen?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int A,B,C,D,Riserva;

    scanf("%d",&A);
    scanf("%d",&B);
    scanf("%d",&C);
    scanf("%d",&D);

    if(A>B)
    else
    {
        Riserva=A;
        A=B;
        B=Riserva;
    }
    if(C>D)
    else
    {
        Riserva=C;
        C=D;
        D=Riserva;
    }
    /*Fine*/
    if(A>C)
        else
        {
            Riserva=A;
            A=C;
            C=Riserva;
        }
    if(B>D)
        else
        {
            Riserva=B;
            B=D;
            D=Riserva;
        }
    /*Fine*/
    if(A>D)
        else
        {
            Riserva=A;
            A=D;
            D=Riserva;
        }
    if(B>C)
        else
        {
            Riserva=B;
            B=C;
            C=Riserva;
        }

    printf("\n\n%d %d %d %d",D,C,B,A);

}
```

Comment: That's not a valid C syntax .

Comment: What should be done if the condition in the `if` is true?

Comment: The number remain the same.

Comment: `else` does not mean `then`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting `C11` standard, chapter §6.8.4.1, the syntax of an `if..else` statement is

> `if` ( expression ) statement `else` statement

If we compare your code, we will see

> `if` ( expression ) `else` statement

which is invalid syntax. You're missing a *statement* there.

You have to put a statement after the `if (condition)` part, being a `;` or `{}` (empty statement). In that case, using the `if...else` does not make much sense. You can reduce the `if...else` check to a single `if` statement, like

```
if(A<=B)   //condition reversed
{
   //previously else block code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You still need a statement even if it's empty.

So something like

```
if(A>B)
{
}
else
{
    Riserva=A;
    A=B;
    B=Riserva;
}
```

But instead it might be easier to simply *reverse* the condition, and do like

```
if(A<=B)
{
    Riserva=A;
    A=B;
    B=Riserva;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the `if` code block contains no statements. You can do this

```
if(A>B);
```

or this

```
if(A>B){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically every 'if' condition evaluation has true and false branch.

You need to provide statements for either only for true branch OR for both true and false branch.So you always need to provide statements for true branch , even if null statement.

In you case , true branch has no statement at all.

So you can fix this by

```
    if(A>C);
    else
    {
        Riserva=A;
        A=C;
        C=Riserva;
    }
```

OR

```
    if(A>C)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        Riserva=A;
        A=C;
        C=Riserva;
    }
```

Note in the first case , there is a NULL statement in true branch ie just semicolons.And in the second case there is a 'true branch' created using curly braces and there is nothing written.